# Consistent drop shadow size on svg path with non-vector scaling

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create an effect on an svg path with `vector="non-scaling-stroke"` with a drop shadow using `filter: drop-shadow(...)`.
However, when the path is scaled to fit the screen (having this scaling is necessary) the path remains a a consistent size but the drop shadow stretches:

```css
svg {
  width: 1000px; /*just to simulate problem, these would be vw & vh units in practice*/
  height: 200px;
}

path {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px blue);
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,30 h50 v70"></path>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the shadow is closely fitted around the horizontal section of the line but more spread on the vertical section. This is expected really but I'm wondering if there's any trick I'm missing to have the shadow be a consistent size around the line for the entire path.

As well as using css filter I've tried:

- using svg filters drop shadow on the path.
- placing a dummy path behind the line with a gaussian blur to simulate a shadow.

Both produce the same result.

I also understand I can resize the svg viewBox to fit the screen with js to avoid the scaling issues altogether but this is really a last resort if there are no other solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue is that what you have is a single path, so there's not a way to make the drop shadow apply differently on a side of your path. What you'll most likely need to do, is convert your SVG to four (or two paths if you are hiding a portion) paths and apply the drop shadow on the top/bottom and sides differently

Comment: Thanks this is a good idea but I'm afraid it won't work for my implementation as I'm animating the line with dash-offset so splitting the path would cause issues with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that this could work!

```css
svg {
  width: 1000px;
  /*just to simulate problem, these would be vw & vh units in practice*/
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M0,30 h50 v70"></path>
   <rect x="0" y="29" width="50" height="2" style="fill:blue;filter: blur(2px);"  />
   <rect x="49.8" y="29" width=".5" height="70" style="fill:blue;filter: blur(.5px);"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks this works well! looks like I'm not getting out of this without using js to scale some values but scaling the rects is easier than scaling the path in my implementation so its alright.